# Не могу отменить действие hover css

Tags: html, css

```css
/*анимация*/
.box {
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    position: relative;
   
    
   
}


.box:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 20px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}

.box:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}

.box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    
   
}



.box:hover img {
    filter: sepia(100%) grayscale(100%);
    transform: scale(1);
}

.box .box-content {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.box:hover .box-content {
    left: 0;
}

.box .title {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #ea1e1f;
    margin: 0;
}

.box .post {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    transition: all 0.8s ease 0.3s;
}

.box .icon {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -100%;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.box:hover .icon {
    right: 2px;
}

.box .icon:after {
    content: "";
    width: 130%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(2, 53, 134);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.box .icon li {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.box .icon li a {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #4285F4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.box .icon li a:hover {
    background: #4285F4;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px #4285F4;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
                        <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/163339/7d336b61-02ed-4c42-a0bf-9a9087b533d4/s1200" alt="1">
                        <div class="box-content">
                            <h3 class="title">pppp</h3>
                            <span class="post">bbbb</span>
                            <span class="post">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque incidunt
                                ad
                                est, fuga obcaecati quidem, quis tenetur voluptate optio, nihil quam maiores mollitia
                                soluta
                                debitis amet qui omnis? Voluptas, culpa!</span>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="icon">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Имеется код. Хотел бы сделать, чтобы при наведении на кнопки справа, менялся текст  в .box-content.
Но почему-то не могу заставить hover работать с этими кнопками. Цвет меняют, а .box-content не хочет. Буду благодарен за кусочек кода.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3">
                    <div class="box">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?> /img/9.jpg" alt="1">
                        <div class="box-content">
                            <h3 class="title">Заголовок</h3>
                            <span class="post">Заголовок</span>
                            <span class="post">Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="icon">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>



.container-fluid{
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

/*анимация*/
.box {
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    position: relative;
}
.box:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 20px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}

.box:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}

.box img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s; 
}

.box:hover img {
    filter: sepia(100%) grayscale(100%);
    transform: scale(1);
}

.box .box-content {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
    background: #352f85;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.box:hover .box-content {
    left: 0;
}


.box .title {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #FFA200;
    margin: 0;
}

.box .post {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transition: all 0.8s ease 0.3s;
}

.box .icon {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -100%;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition: all 0.9s ease 0s;
}

.box:hover .icon {
    right: 2px;
}

.box .icon:after {
    content: "";
    width: 130%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #FFA200;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.box .icon li {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.box .icon li a {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #BF8B30;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.box .icon li a:hover {
    background: #100873;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px #FFA200;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle
}

.link a[rel="category tag"] {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: при наведении на .box выскакивает класс box-content с текстом и icon с кнопками fa fa-bars и fa fa-picture-o. Вот хотелось бы при наведении на эти кнопки менять текст в box-content. Но что-то я даже скрыть этот box-content не могу.

Comment: в box-content имеются <h3 class="title">Заголовок</h3>
                            <span class="post">Заголовок</span>
                            <span class="post">Lorem ipsum dolor</span>  Вот эти классы хотелось бы изменять при наведении. Но что-то не хватает серого вещества в голове.

Comment: хотелось бы без js. Может быть как-то добавить дубль box-content и высвечивать его display:block. А другой скрывать none. третий день голову ломаю.

Comment: может я не правильно выразился. Мне не текст заменить нужно, мне нужно  классы на box-content заменить. на другие title и post.

Comment: приведите в порядок код, что бы можно было вам помочь.

Comment: я добавил пример с картинкой, как он работает сейчас.

Comment: нет. это просто анимация. нужен отклик от кнопок.

Comment: @vadimmegafon при такой разметке это невозможно без JS. CSS селекторы из серии "при наведении на блок A сделать что-то с блоком B" работают только если этот блок B находится где-то ниже в коде от A, и при условии, что A не обернут в какой-то дополнительный блок.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Да. Это то что я хотел. Я был близок)) Но меня вечно тянуло в сторону наименьшего сопротивления. Сделать быстро и потом ругать CSS. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поизвращался... Здесь лучше будет видно, → [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/0d9g6xcw/) (комментарии в коде)

```css
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 20px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}

.box:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.box:hover img {
  filter: sepia(100%) grayscale(100%);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.box .box-content {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0 0 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.box:hover .box-content {
  left: 0;
}

.box:hover .fa {
  right: 4px;
}

.box:hover .blue-box {
  right: 0;
}

.box .title {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px #ea1e1f;
  margin: 0;
}

.box .post {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0.3s;
}

/* До этого ничего не трогал. Отсюда удалил всё, что связано с кнопками
и переписал, мог что-то забыть, полностью не копировал сили*/

/* кнопки */
.box .fa {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: calc(50% - 22px);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #4285F4;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  right: -100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* точная позиция второй кнопки */
.box .fa-link {
  top: calc(50% + 22px);
}

/* между кнопками зазор... при переходе с одной на другую, текст дергается. 
Добавил невидимые 2-пиксельные блоки между ними, для плавного перехода */
.box .fa-link::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  top: -2px;
}

.box .fa-picture-o::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -2px;
}

/* синий фон кнопок */
.blue-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 92px;
  background-color: rgb(2, 53, 134);
  top: calc(50% - 26px);
  right: -100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.box .fa:hover {
  background: #4285F4;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px #4285F4;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.open-1:hover ~ .main,
.open-2:hover ~ .main {
  display: none;
}

.open-1:hover ~ .hidden-1,
.open-2:hover ~ .hidden-2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/163339/7d336b61-02ed-4c42-a0bf-9a9087b533d4/s1200" alt="1">

  <div class="blue-box"></div><!-- синий фон кнопок -->
  <i class="fa fa-picture-o open-1"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-link open-2"></i>
  
  <div class="box-content main">
    <h3 class="title">pppp</h3>
    <span class="post">bbbb</span>
    <span class="post">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box-content hidden hidden-1">
    <h3 class="title">bubu</h3>
    <span class="post">Человек человеку волк...</span>
    <span class="post">А зомби зомби зомби...</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box-content hidden hidden-2">
    <h3 class="title">kuku</h3>
    <span class="post">А на чебурашкины именины...</span>
    <span class="post">Испекли мы каравай...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.s. а захочется добавить 3-ю кнопку - придется опять лезть в CSS и переписывать. Поэтому примерно с этого уровня CSS я бы предпочел перейти на простенькие JS-скрипты, чем столько запариваться со стилями...